# Xamarin - ARGB not working in Windows application

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I have some DataTemplate for Windows GridView in corresponding platform. In this template there should be picture with some text. This text should have background, but only for readibility purposes. I want to have this background to be transparent so image could be seen through it. However, when I set background in format #4C000000, nothing happens and it stays solid black.

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="GridViewPlayerDataTemplate">
            <Grid Height="100" Width="100" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image x:Name="ImageRoleImage" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="{Binding Guess.PlayerRole.ImageSource , Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverterHou}}" />
                <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Opacity="0.1" Grid.RowSpan="1" Background="#4C000000">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockPlayerName" Opacity="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Actor.Name}" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" Background="#4C000000">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockPlayerGuessedRole" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Guess.PlayerRole.Name}" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid> 
        </DataTemplate>
```

I tried to create this pure Windows Store application and transparency works just fine.

Can anyone tell me something about this strange behaviour and/or how to fix it?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you're using Xamarin.Forms but want to use the custom DataTemplate inside a UWP application?

Comment: @hankide yup, I am using custom view with grid view in it and it is in UWP project